# How do I enable HTTP compression in Apache?

Tags: apache, http-compression

What is the recommended way to configure Apache to enable HTTP compression for CSS and JS fiels, using .htaccess? I have seen several different directives used in examples on the web. I have tried some of these and yet I have not been able to get it to work. I am checking the HTTP headers using Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) and [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) are enabled and add something like:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript text/javascript text/css
```

to your `.htaccess`.

See also: http://brightscape.net/blog/compress-your-web-pages-with-mod_deflate/